# ogr2ogr: cannot append data to Carto table. Error returned by server : missing data for column "cartodb_id"

Tags: carto, ogr2ogr

I am trying to import data into CARTO using ogr2ogr.

I can create new tables, but once I try to append new data to this table, I get an error

```
ogr2ogr \
  --config CARTO_API_KEY xxx \
  -t_srs "EPSG:4326" \
  -nln cartolayer \
  -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI \
  -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom \
  -f Carto \
  "Carto:myaccount" \
  mypackage.gpkg \
  -sql 'select * from mylayer' \
  -append
```

**>> Error returned by server : missing data for column "cartodb_id"**

Schema of second table in identical to the one imported first.

I am using GDAL 2.4.0 on a Mac